# make logical screen larger than physical screen?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

In tmux or screen or other, is there a way to make the logical screen larger than the physical screen - so you can (1) scroll around to see the whole screen, and (2) view different parts of the logical screen in different terminals?

Useful for mobile devices with small screens.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wrp/mtm/tree/smtx is not yet mature, but is showing some promise.  I've been using it recently in termux on android to give me arbitrarily wide terminals.  It does not yet support the ability to view different parts of a pty with different windows.

Comment: I just pushed a change that allows multiple windows to connect to a pty, so you can have several views.